# Difference between attributes and style tags in lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I am trying to learn lxml after having used BeautifulSoup.  However, I am not a strong programmer in general.

I have the following code in some source html:

```
<p style="font-family:times;text-align:justify"><font size="2"><b><i> The reasons to eat pickles include:  </i></b></font></p>
```

Because the text is bolded, I want to pull that text.  I can't seem to be able to differentiate that that particular line is bolded.

When I started this work this evening I was working with a document that had the word bold in the style attrib like the following:

```
<p style="font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;margin:0pt 0pt 6.0pt;text-indent:0pt;"><b><i><font size="2" face="Times New Roman" style="font-size:10.0pt;">The reason I like tomatoes include:</font></i></b></p>
```

I should say that the document I am working from is a fragment that I read in the lines, joined the lines together and then used the html.fromstring function

```
txtFile=open(r'c:\myfile.htm','r').readlines()
strHTM=''.join(txtFile)
newHTM=html.fromstring(strHTM)
```

and so the first line of htm code I have above is newHTM[19]

Humm this seems to be getting me closer

```
newHTM.cssselect('b')
```

I don't fully understand yet but here is the solution:

```
for each in newHTM:
    if each.cssselect('b')
        each.text_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the CSS API really isn't the right approach. If you want to find all b elements, do

```
strHTM=open(r'c:\myfile.htm','r').read() # no need to split it into lines first
newHTM=html.fromString(strHTM)
bELements = newHTM.findall('b')
for b in bElements:
    print b.text_content()
```

Comment: This is where I started and it does not work.  As near as I can figure it is because the newHTM is a class and but now I am lost.  I am not sure why I decided to operate on each in newHTM but that was the key.

Comment: Well I am wrong because both newHTM and the each in newHTM are the same type of objects so that is not it

Comment: Well I would edit but I can't fromString sb fromstring and your list is named differently.  But when I run this code on my htm fragment bElements has a length of 0.